# Date validator in Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, validation

I was just wondering how to make a textbox that only accept date as a data. For example, `dd/mm/yyyy`. If user enter april or dd.mm.yyyy, it cant be accepted. Thank you.

Comment: what version of asp ? classic, webforms/mvc 2/3/4 ? Can you be more specific, have you tried google ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try `CompareValidator`.

`<asp:CompareValidator type="Date" Operator="DataTypeCheck" />`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the masked edit textbox extender from the ajax control toolkit. You can see it in action [here](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/MaskedEdit/MaskedEdit.aspx)